# php.ini not being read (Debian / ISP Config)

Tags: php

I have a Debian Squeeze LAMP setup running ISP config. I need to set the date.timezone in the php.ini but it doesn't seem to be reading correctly.

The date.timezone setting is NOT commented out and shows as follows:
date.timezone = "Europe/London"

I had been trying to set this in /etc/php5/apache/php.ini . After inspecting phpinfo() I noticed the loaded configuration file was /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini. So I changed the website settings in ISP config from 'Fast-CGI' to 'Mod-PHP' and the loaded configuration file is now showoing correctly as /etc/php5/apache/php.ini.

Despite resolving the above issue, the phpinfo() is still showing date.timezne (both Local value and Master value) as 'no value'.

can anybody guide me as to what the next step may be?

Answer (score 1):

> To use a custom php.ini file with SuPHP for a website, you can define the path to the php.ini file in a .htaccess file or in the apache vhost like this:
>   suPHP_ConfigPath /home/websites/domain.tld/
>   Then add a php.ini file in the directory /home/websites/domain.tld/ which may be a copy of the global php.ini were you just changed a few settings or an empty file were you add only the settings that shall be overridden in the global PHP configuration.
>   If you use ISPConfig 2 or 3, you can add the suPHP_ConfigPath setting also in the apache directives field of the website  in ISPConfig.

Source: http://www.faqforge.com/linux/controlpanels/ispconfig2/how-to-use-a-custom-php-ini-with-suphp/

I think it will gonna help you with your php.ini modifications.
Hope it helps