# upload script not working after enabling suphp

Tags: .htaccess, upload, php, suphp

My php script that uploads files in my centos - apache server was working fine.
Today I enabled suphp in server and after that script is not uploading any files.
I was used "php_flag register_globals on" in .htaccess before. But I removed that line from ".htaccess" in order to prevent 500 server error.
Pls help

Comment: do you have access to the server logs?

Comment: right, try to upload an image and check your server logs, with any luck you'll have something in there that will point to whats causing the problem. My guess is you have permissions problems.

Comment: changed permissions according to suphp. But not succeeded!

Answer (score 0):

After a long search and testing, I found the solution myself.
Just created a php.ini file and added a line:
register_global = on

and removed all php flags in .htaccess.
Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

As you figured out the parameter has to be in a **php.ini** file and suPHP has to be instructed to read this file. More information in this answer: [php.ini not being read (Debian / ISP Config)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370192/php-ini-not-being-read-debian-isp-config)

**But;** If your upload script requires `register_globals` to be enabled it's probably badly written or outdated. You should try to avoid using `register_globals` since it poses a security threat. More about that here: [What are register_globals in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593210/what-are-register-globals-in-php)